# The Nginx reverse proxy does not reach the app via the internal route after restarting

Tags: dns, routes, nginx-reverse-proxy, swisscomdev

We have the following setup: nginx buildpack as reverse proxy with proxy_pass set to an internal route *.apps.internal. The setup works fine until the app to which the internal route leads restarts. Then we have the problem that the app gets a new internal IP address and the internal DNS does not immediately resolve the internal route *.apps.internal to the new IP address. Are we missing some settings?

A manual restart of the reverse proxy solves the problem. However, this is not a long-term solution.

Comment: This is normal as nginx will cache the DNS for a while. Probably this is configurable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably using Nginx `resolver` could help, from the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver):

> Configures name servers used to resolve names of upstream servers into 
>       addresses, for example:
>        resolver 127.0.0.1 [::1]:5353;

You could use it globally:

```
resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 10s;

location /foo {
    set $foo_backend_servers foo_backends.example.com;
    proxy_pass http://$foo_backend_servers;
 }
```

Or per location:

```
location /foo {
    proxy_pass http://foo_backends;
    resolver 10.0.0.2 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;
}
```

Problem is to know what DNS server to use, from these links:

- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack/pull/12
- https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack/issues/8

`resolver 169.254.0.2;` is used, just in case, the `169.254.0.0/16` IPv4 range belongs to the [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address), so better double check what DNS server to use.